# Typescript: How do I define interfaces for nested objects?

Tags: typescript

Assume I have a JSON payload that parses into something like this:

```
{
    name: "test",
    items: {
        "a": {
            id: 1,
            size: 10
        },
        "b": {
            id: 2,
            size: 34
        }
    }
}
```

How would I set up the definition of the Example interface to model that the value of the items property is an object whose keys are strings and whose values are defined by the Item interface:

```
export interface Example {
    name: string;
    items: ???;

}

export interface Item {
    id: number;
    size: number;
}
```

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Typescript allows you to add a type for the object keys using the syntax `[key: string]`.

As stated in the documentation, these are called [indexable types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

> Indexable types have an index signature that describes the types we can use to index into the object, along with the corresponding return types when indexing.

In your case, you would use the following:

```
export interface Item {
    id: number;
    size: number;
}

export interface Example {
    name: string;
    items: {
        [key: string]: Item
    };
}
```

For reference, here is a [link to a live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Item%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Example%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20items%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Item%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20obj%3A%20Example%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22test%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20items%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22a%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%3A%2010%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22b%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%3A%2034%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: Why do you export `Item` interface? Isn't exporting just `Example` interface enough?

Comment: @AlexanderKim yes, unless `Item` is useful to other code using these types as well.

Comment: does anyone know how to set the items keys with state and access them?

Comment: @Dog of course but this is not a "code for me" website

Comment: Thanks for this I had an issue accessing an interface defined in one class file in another class. I had not defined the interface with export. After adding the export the import at the to of the page allowed me to then import the class and the interface thanks.

Comment: @josh-crozier can you please update the documentation links with the most recent ones? Thank you. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures

Comment: @MarcoR. - updated, thanks for letting me know the previous one was deprecated!

Comment: You're more than welcome and your answer was very useful to me. Thank you!

Comment: Is that needed to point that key is a string ?

Answer (score 9):

You can want can be achieved using Record type

```
interface Item {
    id: number;
    size: number;
}


interface Example2 {
   name: string;
   items : Record<string, Item>; 

}

var obj2: Example2 = {
    name: "test",
    items: {
        "a": {
            id: 1,
            size: 10
        },
        "b": {
            id: 2,
            size: 34
        },
        "c": {
            id: 3,
            size: 34
        }
    }
}
```

You will also get compile time check:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `Record` can also be a `Record`.

```
type Weekday = 'Monday' | 'Tuesday' | 'Wednesday' | 'Thursday' | 'Friday'
type Animal = 'duck' | 'goose' | 'chicken'

type FarmReport = {
    name: string
    items: Record<Weekday, Record<Animal, number>>
    reporter: string
} 

const report: FarmReport = {
    name: 'report 20231101',
    reporter: 'Tom',
    items: {
        'Monday' : {
            duck: 1,
            goose: 2,
            chicken: 3,
        },
        'Tuesday' : {
            duck: 1,
            goose: 2,
            chicken: 3,
        },
        'Wednesday' : {
            duck: 1,
            goose: 2,
            chicken: 3,
        },
        'Thursday' : {
            duck: 1,
            goose: 2,
            chicken: 3,
        },
        'Friday' : {
            duck: 1,
            goose: 2,
            chicken: 3,
        },
    }
}
```

This is a straightforward way (firstly define Weekday and Animal, then define FarmReport) to have a nested `Record`. [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

Another way is to use `keyof` to do it reversely (firstly define FarmReport, then define Weekday and Animal as being extracted from FarmReport). [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html)