# creating simple object in ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have interface

```
export interface Vehicle {
    IdNumber: number;    
    isNew: boolean;
    contact: { 
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
        cellPhoneNumber: number;            
    };
    color: string;
}
```

Inside component I'm importing this interface.

```
 let car: Vehicle = {
      IdNumber: 1,
      isNew: true,
      contact: {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        cellPhoneNumber: 123,            
      },
      color: 'red',          
    };
```

I cannot compile this code cause webpack reporting following error

> Types of property 'contact' are incompatible.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't declare sub-objects like this in TS interfaces. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42216124/3820185

Comment: You can. It compiles just fine on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Comment: works for me. What version of TS do you use?

Comment: It works perfectly. Consider type checking directly with `tsc --noEmit` and telling whatever TypeScript loader you are using with Webpack not to typecheck.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors:

Mismatched property names:

```
isExisting vs isNew // pick one...
```

Type error:

```
color: red // 'red' needs quote marks to be a string
```

Hope that clears it up...