# How to map DTO using interfaces in typescript?

Tags: typescript, dto

I am trying to implement morphism/DTO mapping concept in typescript.

To give a brief overview on the concept of morphism, morphism refers to a structure-preserving map from one mathematical structure to another. 
A morphism f with source X and target Y is written f : X → Y.

More on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism

I am trying to do source to destination mapping of a complex type object (i.e an object containing another object and arrays of object) in generic way using StrictSchema of morphism. Please refer to link provided below to get more on morphism npm package.
https://github.com/nobrainr/morphism

my interface

```
            interface IFoo {  
                  keyA: {
                  key1: number,
                  key2: number,
                  key3: [
                    {
                      key3A: string,
                      key3B: number
                    }
                  ],
                  key4: string
                },
                keyB: string,
                keyC: number,
                keyD: {
                  key1: string,
                  key2: {
                    key2A: string
                  },
                  key3: string
                },
                keyE: string
            }


            const schema: StrictSchema<IFoo> = 
            {  keyA: {
                  key1: 'somepath',
                  key2: 'somepath',
                  key3: [
                    {
                      key3A: 'somepath',
                      key3B: 'somepath'
                    }
                  ],
                  key4: 'somepath'
                },
                keyB: 'somepath',
                keyC: 'somepath',
                keyD: {
                  key1: 'somepath',
                  key2: {
                    key2A: 'somepath'
                  },
                  key3: 'somepath'
                },
                keyE: 'somepath'
            };

        const target = morphism(schema, someSourceObject);
```

Here, schema is the object-preserving map for my interface. I have added 'somepath' as a value for each key and I will replace this with some actual path from the actual source object.
but while doing so I am getting:
Error : The expected type comes from property 'keyA' which is declared here on type 'StrictSchema

So, First of all, can I preserve mapping in above scenarieo using morphism because I have not come accross any such examples using 'ScrictSchema'. If yes, then how?

Comment: try and simplify your problem to a small reproducible example with only a few keys.

Comment: hi @shusson, that is exactly how I am getting the issue, while mapping the object with hierarchical structure. I have added an object as well as an  array to make it more clear.

Comment: I mean reduce the complexity of your example. Find a minimally reproducible example. That way it's easier for people to understand and answer

Answer (score 3):

Just a follow up about the request. Beside of the suggestion to break down the interface in smaller schemas, I also implemented the ability to create a complex object from the schema. Available in the latest version of [Morphism: 1.9.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morphism)

Here's the [Github Issue](https://github.com/nobrainr/morphism/issues/50#issuecomment-474120987) and a [working repl](https://repl.it/@yrnd1/Morphism-Complex-Object-using-StrictSchema)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement your interface for a strict schema using nested interfaces or complex interface signatures.

Here is a StackOverflow link on how to achieve the same : [Typescript: How do I define interfaces for nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216053/typescript-how-do-i-define-interfaces-for-nested-objects)

Alternatively you can use different npm package for domain to model mapping in typescript like Automapper for typescript( https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper )

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, and I am using it perfectly, but I am not sure if it fits you.

```
/**
 * @description MAP T over K and produce T
 */
export const mapper = <T, K>(object: K): T => {
    let obj = {} as T;

    Object.keys(object).map(key => {
        if (instanceOf<T>(object, key)) {
            // @ts-ignore
            obj[key] = object[key];
        }
    });

    return obj;
};

function instanceOf<T>(object: any, key: string): object is T {
    return key in object;
}
```

Later use it like.

```
const obj = mapper<CreateAddressInterface, AddressInterface>(selectedAddress);
```