# typescript/angular: can't iterate over Map parsed from json

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm new to both typescript and angular (coming from quite solid Java/kotlin background). 
Wrote a class:

```
export interface GeoData {
    allregions: Map<string, string>;
}
```

to parse this json:

```
{"allregions":{"whatever":"WHT","a region":"ARE","something":"SMT"}
```

The json is correctly read from a file using `HttpClient.get()` and I can see the correct content in the variable using debug. also, this code:

```
console.log(data.allregions["whatever"])
```

correctly prints `WHT`.

unfortunately, this:

```
data.allregions.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
        console.log(key, value);
    });
```

throws `data.allregions.forEach is not a function`

also this:

```
console.log(data.allregions.size)
```

prints `undefined`

and this:

```
console.log(data.allregions.entries.lenght)
```

throws `data.allregions.entries is undefined`

what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are applying forEach on a object. Combine **Object.keys()** and **forEach()**

```js
var data = {"allregions":{"whatever":"WHT","a region":"ARE","something":"SMT"}}
Object.keys(data.allregions).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(`key: ${key}, value:${data.allregions[key]}`);
});
```

Comment: thank you, that works. But is it wrong how I wrote the interface for this json? Is that a way to parse it so it's actually parsed into a map?

Comment: @jack_the_beast it would be better if you be more concise on type of data it should actually contain. Like defining your interface to the most nested level. Check this for some insight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216053/typescript-how-do-i-define-interfaces-for-nested-objects