# Typescript N nested object with function as values

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I would like to have a type that relates to an object with N level of nested keys and values being functions that returns strings.

Ideally I would like to have the value of the function being displayed in a tooltip instead of string type (od as a const shows me the value instead of string which I want)
Like this bu this is very cumbersome.

```js
const endpoints = {
  hierarchy: {
    od: () => `....` as const,
    sd: () => `.....`,
  },
  a: { b: { c: (a: string) => 'asdsd' } },
} as const
```

How I can make a type that would resolve to such structure?

Comment: take look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216053/typescript-how-do-i-define-interfaces-for-nested-objects

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wRzAnw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz if you reply, to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz it's somewhat close but not exactly what I need. When I hover over the hierarchy key it shows me the values of the od sd but when I hover over od or sd it shows as string, secondly it allows me to define a key with any value so it can be a: 1 but I need it to conform only to the key: function with return type of string always

Comment: 1) "when I hover over od or sd it shows as string"  I cannot reproduce; can you demonstrate this? 2) For the other issue I'd take [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJ71rw).  Let me know what to do here, especially with the hovering issue which I am not seeing; I see the string literal types only and not `string` in my IDE.  (Pls ping via @jcalz)